# K-means clustering when k is initially 1 during training but becomes 2 as more instances arrive

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset or both anomalous and normal instances. These data instances are arranged based on arrival time from January 1st until December 31st.

I want to cluster these data points, but the assumption is that I only have 2weeks worth of data initially (but these initial data points contain only normal instances). So when I run clustering on these initial points with a K-value of 2 (k=2 because normal/anomaly) with an intention of using the centroids to predict new data points, then K-means will say that there exist two clusters even though these 2 weeks data contains only normal instances. Hence, when an actual attack comes in, it will be misclassified as belonging to one of the initial 2 clusters which also contains normal instances.

Does it mean K-means cannot be used to solve real-time (time/date based) problems when you don't have both normal and attack instances to start off the cluster centroids?

Does the effect above imply that I can't use K-means to solve my problem? If it doesn't how can I solve this issue? If it does, which ML algorithm will be well suited for this problem?

Comment: K-means will always force data to be divided into k (k>=2) clusters because it is a stiff divisive method. I think that for this and probably other reasons it doesn't suit your task.

Comment: KMeans is sensitive to outliers. I also don't think it is a good choice in this setting. Have you considered one-class classification and outlier detection?